# Property or method "Userdata" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is reactive, either in

Tags: vue.js, v-model

I’m trying to save an input value with v-model property by vuejs component.

I want to use a vue component to save a product with a `Userdata` property I define an object in data section and use that in blade with v-model. But I recieve an error:

> Property or method "Userdata" is not defined on the instance but
> referenced during render

This is my component:

```
    <template>
        <div >
            <table class="blueTable">
                <thead >
                    <th></th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="product in products " :key="product.product_id" class="{ selected: isSelected }">
                        <td class="product_name "> {{ product . product_name }} </td>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </template>
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    import Vue from 'vue';
    import axios from "axios";

    export default{  
        mounted() {  
            
        },  
        data() {  
            return {  
                products: [],
                loading: false,
                buttonsLoading: [],
                Userdata: {
                    product_name: '',
                    product_id:0,
                },
            };  
        },  
        
        created: function () {
            this.loadproducts();
        },
        methods: {  
            loadproducts() {  
                let url = "/product_listvue";
                axios
                    .get(url)
                    .then((response) => {
                        this.products = response.data;
                    })
                    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
            },
            
            async delproductvue  (product_id)  {
                Vue.set(this.buttonsLoading, product_id, 1);
                this.loading = true;
                let url = "/delproductvue/" + product_id;
                try {
                    let response = await axios.post(url);
                    if (response.status == 419) {
                        alert('لطفا صفحه را رفرش و دوباره تلاش نمایید.');
                    }
                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        console.log(response.status);
                    }
                    this.products = response.data;
                    this.loading = false;
                }
                catch (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                    alert(err);
                    this.loading = false;
                }
            },
            
            storeproductvue: function ()  {
                let formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('product_id', p_id);
                var file_data = $('#image').prop('files')[0];
                form_data.append('image', file_data);
                form_data.append('_name', this.Userdata.product_name);
            
                Vue.set(this.buttonsLoading, product_id, 1);
                this.loading = true;
                let url = "/storeproductvue/";
                    let response =  axios.post(url,form_data);
                    if (response.status == 200) {
                        console.log(response.status);
                    }
                    this.products = response.data;
                    this.loading = false;
        }
        }
        
    </script>
```

blade:

```
<div id="app" style="overflow-y: scroll;">
        <input type="text" id="product_name" class="form-control" v-model="Userdata.product_name">
        <!-- <button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" v-on:click="storeproductvue()"> vueذخیره</button> -->
        <product_list>
            </-product_list>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the response from '/product_listvue' is an array that contains objects having a property named "Product_name"?

Comment: If the vue component you've provided is a `ProductList` component, then how can you use the component data outside the component context? I think you've to define new data or the component should be defined with props.

Comment: Also, the error you've written in the question and the error you've provided inside the question context are different. Please fix that.

Comment: is it possible to use data in el tag for example #app DIV in outside of component or not?